# Кто такие "граммарнаци"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Сейчас в сети, особенно среди малограмотных подростков, ставящих себе собственную безграмотность чуть ли не в заслугу, распространен термин "граммарнаци". Но, честно говоря, я не очень понимаю, по отношению к кому он употребляется. Являемся ли, например, мы все тут, пишущие более-менее грамотно, "граммарнаци"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Граммарнаци - это не те кто пишут грамотно, а те кто по поводу и без, указывают на орфографические, реже пунктационные, ошибки других.

Когда в какой-либо теме вместо обсуждения проблемы начинают разбирать грамотность участников ни к какому конструктиву это не приведёт. Поэтому к "граммарнаци" отношение как правило не очень дружелюбное.

Comment: Ну а, с другой стороны, если никто не будет высмеивать и ругать подростков за чудовищную безграмотность, они так и будут издеваться над русским языком и ставить себе это в заслугу.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, тут вопрос этики и его каждый решает для себя сам. Вы будете пенять своим знакомым, если они будут есть мясо без помощи ножа? Если это приём у английской королевы может и шикну, а в непринуждённой обстановке, даже не обращу внимание Я - нет. Более того, если в доме, где я гость, принято есть ножа, то просить его считаю неприличным.

Грамотность - это тот же кухонный нож, правильнее есть с ним, но и без него обойтись тоже можно, блюдо от этого хуже не станет. Так и грамотность, если мысль интересная, то мне безразлично сколько орфографических ошибок в этой мысли.

Comment: Да, и еще — поборники чистоты языка и абсолютной грамотности бывают разные. Мне по духу ближе всего те, что с лицом [вида «Христос несет крест на Голгофу»](http://s019.radikal.ru/i619/1408/6f/db89c93e6e8b.jpg) наблюдают за тем, как великий и могучий превращается в жалкий и никчемный.

Answer (score 5):

Граммар-наци – это люди, которые постоянно указывают другим на ошибки (орфографические, грамматические, пунктуационные), а также относятся свысока к людям, чья грамотность ниже. Главные черты ГН – это агрессивность (резкое осуждение человека за ошибки) и гордость за свою высокую грамотность (то есть сами они всегда стараются писать абсолютно грамотно в любой ситуации).

Answer (score 2):

Кстати, а можно ли считать граммарнаци девушку из этого диалога (она тоже указывает на безграмотность своему оппоненту):

[image]

Comment: Судя по имени, русский язык для Самандара неродной, а для иностранца он владеет русским очень даже неплохо.

Comment: Нет, девушка не граммарнаци, она в своём праве.)))
"В ответ дивчина гордая шутила, видно, с ним: "Когда вернёшься с орденом, тогда поговорим!"